looking to up their bartake

Soon all the fashionable Melbourne discos and clubs were looking to up their bartake with regular live band bookings, and Michael shrewdly seized the opportunity to establish his own booking agency, which he named the Australian Entertainment Exchange.'

Could you reword the bolded?

What does it mean? They want more revenue from the bar? Cambridge Dictionary has for the verb up To increase something such as a price: We won't be able to make a profit on the deal without upping the sale price.

bartake=the take (revenue) from the bar. Look up the noun take.

"trying to increase their bar revenues" WTP?

This question is similar to: "I've been looking to do [this or that]." Is "looking to do" idiomatic?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. // The second question (the meaning of 'bartake') involves a candidate, either protologism or neologism, compound noun. I can't find many mentions on the internet.

If all you want is to reword the bolded '… looking to up their bartake…', that would be something such as '… hoping to achieve greater takings at their bar.' Was that really all you wanted? Either way, what did the previous Question leave out?

When we are "looking to" do something, we have set it as a goal.

They are looking to hike the entire Appalachian Trail.

up can be used informally as a verb, meaning to increase.

Let's up the ante to $100 for this round of poker.

bartake is formed by analogy with "intake", which in a business context refers to the revenue that comes in from the sale of goods or services.  It is the revenue from the sale of alcoholic beverages at the "bar".  "bar" there is used metonymically to refer to those beverage sales as a whole, including beverages served at tables not at the actual bar.
